# Does anybody have idea about this Veracode Flaw "Information Exposure Through Sent Data"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uri, veracode

I have a mvc application in which there is a low veracode flaw on this line

Information exposure through sent data

```
 private WebResponse GetCreditCheckResponse(Uri uri)
    {
        WebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            #region Logging
            LogManager.Info("Enter - " + "Accessing uri: " + uri);
            #endregion
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri); //Veracode Flaw in this line
```

The value for uri is "{https://www.p6.experian.nl/cgi-bin/retrieve?PROCESSID=150&PREFIX=&INITIALS=B&SURNAME=Klomp&DATEOBIRTH=31031964&GENDER=&POSTALCODE=3846BN&HOUSENUM=22&HOUSEEXT=&PHONENUMBER=&FORMAT=XML&FULLSIZE=TRUE&HOUSEEXTIGNORE=TRUE&D-INDUSTRY_SEC=2&D-DATA_LEVEL=1&D-LIFE_CYCLE=1&D-VERSION_NUM=2}"

Can anybody help me with this flaw?

Comment: Does anybody has any idea on how to resolve this??